# Getting Request JSON type as buffer

Tags: node.js, restify

I have a function that process JSON. It's called by a route handler. Instead of getting JSON string, that function is getting this-

```
{"type": "Buffer", "data": [123,122,22,....]}
```

Because of that, I cannot parse JSON. What is causing this issue?

I'm passing JSON such as -

```
{"id": "123", "username": "abc",...}
```

And my code is -

```
server.post('/pages', restify.jsonBodyParser(),createPage);
function createPage(req, res, next)
{
   myfunction(req,res);

   next();
}

function myfunction(req,res){
   console.log(req);
}
```

And this is the request header -

```
{"authorization":"Basic xxxxxxx","accept":"application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml","user-agent":"RestSharp/105.0.1.0","content-type":"Application/Json", "host":"remoteserver.com:xxx","cookie":"sessionid=36yTgWtzpSR4VrvRikTEzfu8wBcPLWTQARtLgT63","content-length":"4246","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Restify's body parser middleware doesn't like `Application/Json` as content type, it only accepts `application/json` (which AFAIK is a bug as mime-types should be treated case-insensitive; issue submitted [here](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/877)).

If you can't change the client, you can use a Restify middleware that will lowercase the header:

```
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (typeof req.headers['content-type'] === 'string') {
    req.headers['content-type'] = req.headers['content-type'].toLowerCase();
  }
  next();
});
```

You have to include that before using `restify.jsonBodyParser()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if your suggestion would resolve my issue since I changed "myfunction" to process string type and pass just req.body instead of req object. But it does resolve issues of having to JSON.parse body. I mark it as a correct answer anyway as I believe that to be a culprit. But I'll do testing to confirm that so other people who may have similar issues can be sure about it.

Comment: Ok I just changed my function back to original one and tested your solution. Yep you are right. That's the reason I'm getting that strange data structure. Thanks!